# Use of "for example" in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Is use of "for example" in the following sentences correct grammatically and conceptually? If it is not , kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> In all of turbomachineries, there are different kinds of losses as
>   follows:
>
> · External losses
>
> · Internal losses
>
> External losses are not computed by CFD methods and are, for example,
>   losses in bearings and gears.

I want to say that losses due to bearings and gears aren't included in computations by CFD method. It is better to start the sentence with "External losses" after writing:

> · External losses
>
> · Internal losses

Comment: You could trim it and tidy it up by saying: In all turbo-machinery there are both internal and external losses. External losses such as those due to bearings and gears are not computed by CFD methods. Although I'm not familiar with the engineering vocabulary, I would lose the "of" before turbo-machineries and keep the word singular. While in this context I prefer "such as" to "for example", that may be just a matter of taste.

Comment: It looks OK to me, although I think an even clearer way to phrase it would be "External losses are not computed by CFD methods; examples of external losses include losses in bearings and gears."

Comment: Ronald Sole, "such as those due to" is right??

Comment: @user19061 There are a number of options that you could use here: "due to", "owing to", "arising from", "caused by", "resulting from". They all serve to link the set "external losses" to particular examples of those losses.

Comment: OK, but i want to know phrase ""such as those due to" is right?
This seems inappropriate for me.